# Will Ionic 1.0 be deprecated now that 2.0 has been released?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I spent a lot of time learning ionic so I could build my app. I just happened to learn today that there is a version 2 now that requires a whole other language.
What I want to know is if I keep building my current app with version 1, will there be problems when I deploy it? Will things become non functional when version 2 becomes the standard?

Answer (score 0):

After 1 year, I am also looking for answer to this question. Only thing I've already found is [this discussion](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/is-there-any-plan-to-deprecate-discontinue-ionic-v1/96442) on `ionic forum`. If I will find more, I will update this answer.